# Grails Getting Started package helloworld

Tags: grails, grails-3.0

I am trying to run "package helloworld" on W8.1, and I get:

```
grails> package helloworld  
| Error Caught exception Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'http
s://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.3-bin.zip'.
Problem with provided build arguments: [-helloworld].
Unknown command-line option '-h'.
Either it is not a valid build option or it is not supported in the target Gradl
e version.
Not all of the Gradle command line options are supported build arguments.
Examples of supported build arguments: '--info', '-u', '-p'.
Examples of unsupported build options: '--daemon', '-?', '-v'.
Please find more information in the javadoc for the BuildLauncher class. (Use --
stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

*Any help would be appreciated.*

Comment: What exactly you're trying to do? if you want to generate war try `grails> assemble` also when you're in grails console with the help of tab you can view all available commands.

Answer (score 0):

nvm, I feel like an idiot. ;-)

I was following along in the helloworld example in [Getting Started](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/guide/gettingStarted.html#aHelloWorldExample), and I thought I was supposed to add an action in the Grails interactive console. What I needed to do was edit the controller template script created in the previous step. My bad, sorry about that.

Thank you to everyone.